# Ubuntu 20.04 lts wifi-hotspot not working

Tags: ubuntu, wifi-hotspot

I have a TP-Link T6e card on my computer and it works fine after installing the drivers from the additional driver tabs found in ubuntu software and updates , meaning that I can connect to a wifi. But, when I try to make a hotspot using the option found in ubuntu wifi settings it does not work. What it does is that it creates an ad-hoc connection instead of a hotspot one. I tried editing it using :

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi-connection
```

but if I close and reopen the hotspot it makes it ad-hoc again.

Any suggestions on how to solve this frustrating issue?

Comment: Welcome, Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626452/153195, if you found it useful, I will answer your question.

Comment: There is no AP in supported interfaces. I think I got tricked by the seller. Anyway, do you know a fairly cheap (under 50$) network card that supports both AP and Ubuntu?

Comment: For example [on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/NETELY-Laptop-Qualcomm-Adapter-Mini-Card-802-11N-300Mbps-Mini/dp/B07FMHFGD1/ref=pd_lpo_147_t_0/145-4208706-3746022?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B07FMHFGD1&pd_rd_r=a2310207-71ec-4066-862b-66dea9978143&pd_rd_w=2Gxrw&pd_rd_wg=R854n&pf_rd_p=7b36d496-f366-4631-94d3-61b87b52511b&pf_rd_r=4FD1JRHHEF9WB79ZM9WQ&psc=1&refRID=4FD1JRHHEF9WB79ZM9WQ).

Comment: It's unavailable. Anything available? Maybe a pci-e?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your wifi card support the AP mode:

```
sudo iw list |grep -i "Supported interface modes:" -A10
```

It should print:

```
...
* AP
...
```

See: [Wi-Fi device must support AP mode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#Wi-Fi_device_must_support_AP_mode)

Use the [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) tools to create an AP (See: [linux-wifi-hotspot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Software_access_point#linux-wifi-hotspot)):

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
sudo make install
```

Then use [Internet sharing from the same WiFi interface](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap#internet-sharing-from-the-same-wifi-interface):

```
create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

or if you need the Ethernet connection through your Wifi interface:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```